# Is this benchmark sufficient to consider my algorithm as an efficient matrix multiplication algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, matrix-multiplication

I built a matrix multiplication algorithm and now I need some thoughts about following benchmark.

C++ chrono:: high resolution clock Time(micro second)

1. (Dim)256--> (Naive algo ) 296807, (My algo) 187479
2. (Dim)512--> (Naive algo) 2249495, (My algo) 1359046
3. (Dim)1024-->(Naive algo) 27930970, (My algo) 12309645

FYI, I have no knowledge about strassen matrix multiplication algorithm and how to utilize a github project.Therefore,I stole some benchmark from a github account for sake of some comparisons with strassen matrix mulplication algorithm.Those are as below.

C++ chrono:: high resolution clock Time(micro second)

1. (Dim)256-->(Naive algo) 260281,(Strassen algo) 216970
2. (Dim)512--> (Naive algo) 2122299, (Strassen algo) 1580466
3. (Dim)1024-->(Naive algo) 2algorithm?Strassen algo) 14696774

I don't know specs of github user's computer.I assume it's better than mine after observing both execution times of naive matrix multiplication algorithm.(quoted from https://github.com/rangelak/Strassen-Matrix-Multiplication)

Specs of my computer

Processor core i7 6th gen(2.60 GHz)

Ram 8gb

What do you think about my algorithm after observing above mentioned band what can I expect after comparing my algorithm with strassen matrix multiplication algorithm?

Comment: You should run all three yourself to properly compare. You can copy the single file `strassen.cpp` and compile it with `g++ strassen.cpp`. Put the entries of the matrices $A$ and $B$ to be multiplied in a file `matrices.txt`. The entries go one per line, in row-major order, with the entries of $B$ following those of $A$. Then call the executable with `./a.out 0 n matrices.txt`, where $n$ is the dimension of the matrices. You can uncomment the lines for timing.

Comment: This isn’t computer science anyway, but I would strongly recommend testing sizes that are not powers of two. And twelve seconds for n=1,024 seems poor. Are you using SIMD? FMA? Blocking?

Comment: @gnasher729 [Experimental computer science](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~brecht/courses/854-Experimental-Performance-Evaluation-2018/readings/feitelson-exp05.pdf).

Comment: So,What is the lowest execution time currently acquired by a matrix multiplication algorithm for dim 1024 ? @gnasher729

Comment: I don’t know. But an 8 core processor at 3GHz doing 4 fused multiply-adds per cycle is quite affordable, so a goal for straightforward matrix multiplication of size 32x 32 would be not much more than 10ms. You need to make use of all cores, use 256 bit vector instructions, and organise memory access to be perfectly cache friendly.

Comment: I will try it.thank you for your instructions. @gnasher729

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one thing I want to mention is that the strassen's matrix multiplication algorithm isn't often used in the real world and your algo is probably faster if the $n$ stays below a few thousands (explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13559928/why-is-my-strassens-matrix-multiplication-slow).
Now if you still want to compare your algorithm to the strassens algorithm I would recommend you to copy past a function from somewhere and run it on your computer.
The algorithm would get the same input as your algo and would run on the same hardware.

Here are some implementation of strassens algo:

vectors:
https://github.com/dmonaldo/strassen-matrix-multiplication/blob/master/main.cpp

arrays:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strassens-matrix-multiplication-algorithm-implementation/

When I benchmark an algorithm I always want to plot the results to visualize the complexity. I think more is better; so you should probably use more n not only 256, 512, 1024. Also it would be good to know if your algo is made for a special case like sparse matrices etc. if that's the case you need to pay close attention to the input data, otherwise one algo might have a disadvantage.

Comment: Thank you for the advice.As you said I tested my algo for special cases (dim)1023 -->(time)12446166 , (dim)1025--> (time)12964602,(dim)511--> (time)1359526  and (dim)513--> (time)1432035.I also tested on several sparse matrixes it worked perfectly.and finally I tested strassen matrix algo on my PC for dimension size 512 it took 33147590 micro second(geekforgeek).I also would like to know What is the lowest execution time currently acquired by a matrix multiplication algorithm for dim 1024 ? @plshelp

Comment: well if you are feeling bold you could run your naive algorithm with -O3 as a compilation flag (command line argument). This optimization turns loop unrolling and vectorized instructions on, which will make the naive algorithm extremely fast. Now the algorithms used in practice for machine learning are parallelized and (usually) take advantage of the GPU. They aren't comparable to single-thread algos. Although there might be a better implementation of the strassen algo than that of geeks for geeks.

Comment: You practically meant I should run my algo on GPU like on CUDA parallel programming platform then figure out what is the execution time for my algo on GPU power.is it? @plshelp

Comment: No you asked something like "whats the fastest algo currently available for 1024 matrices?" and i wanted to say that fastest way currently available is matrix multiplication via gpu. To run your algorithm on GPU would require you to rewrite a completely different algorithm and thus doesn't make much sense. But now I'm curious, are you writing something for a research paper or whats your mission?

Comment: Actually, there's no exact mission here,I am simply trying find a way to optimize my algo and also trying to figure out is this algo good to be included on a my own github account because currently I don't have a github account. @plshelp